# how get and save a return value of post request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api

I have a post requested (API) that returns a Integer. How can i save this value on ajax call.

here the function ajax.

```
$(function () {
    $("#Login").submit(function (e) {

        var Admin = new Object();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            content: "json",
            url: 'http://localhost:6735/api/Login',
            data: Admin,  
            crossDomain: true,
            async: false,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
            },
```

here is the api request

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Login")]
public int Post([FromBody]Admin data)
{
    //  var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var username =data.UserName;
    var password = data.Password;

    Adminassembly searchusernamepassword = new Adminassembly();
    return searchusernamepassword.checkUser(username, password);

}
```

Comment: Where do you want to save it? Are you sure the value is returning from the POST call? In your $.ajax() 'success' function, what is the value returned in data?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data) {
        // 'data' is what is returned from the API. 
        // Log it or save it to some global or local JS var.
            },
```

Also in the following snippet, url should just be `api/Login` if you are hosting the HTML page on the same server as the API.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            content: "json",
            url: 'http://localhost:6735/api/Login',
```